# shell_exec using ajax call does not work in inux

Tags: php, ajax, ubuntu, sh, sudo

I have a php script that uses a shell_exec to call a shell script, I am using a ajax call to the php script,

In mac os, it does run without any issues, but when I try to run it in my ubuntu vm, it does not do the shell_exec command when called from the ajax, but if I run from the unix console using

```
php script.php
```

it does run the shell_exec normally.

Anyone has had this issue before?

The php code is this

```
<?php

 $output = shell_exec('sudo sh /var/www/html/SIRSProject/WebApp/php/teste.sh'); 

 echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Change the file permissions of your shell script with  `chmod 777 teste.sh` and try again, maybe without sudo

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is because when called via the web server the command will run as another user compared to when you call it directly on the command line.

Which web server are you using? If you're running `apache` for example you can see/change the user PHP is run as by the webs server in the [`User` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unixd.html#user); under Ubuntu this `www-data`.

Another reason may be that `sudo` ask for a password which can not be provided by PHP. Note here: when running on the terminal `sudo` may cache the authorization *for that terminal session*. So maybe also test manually executing the PHP script in a new terminal session.

In both cases you may need to update your [`/etc/sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudoers.man.html) to allow for non-interactive execution of `sudo`.

## But be aware: THIS IS DANGEROUS!

Calling an external command with `sudo` from a web server can easily become a huge security risk by allowing to execute commands with root privileges from the web. Only proceed with this if you really know what you are doing - especially never trust the user input!